# Tensorflow installation - Double requirement given

Tags: python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-14.04, tensorflow

I got the following error when installing tensorflow using the command:

`sudo pip3 install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL`

I also tried without the `--upgrade` but to no avail:

`sudo pip3 install $TF_BINARY_URL`

The environment variable / OS / Python / CUDA Toolkit / CuDNN as obtained from the tensorflow install instructions:

```
# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, GPU enabled, Python 3.4 
# Requires CUDA toolkit 7.5 and CuDNN v4. For other versions, see "Install from sources" below.
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.9.0rc0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

The error message is:

```
Double requirement given: tensorflow==0.9.0rc0 from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.9.0rc0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl (already in tensorflow, name='tensorflow')
```

Here is the `~/.pip/pip.log`:

```
/usr/bin/pip3 run on Wed Jun 15 23:13:09 2016
Downloading/unpacking https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.9.0rc0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl
  Downloading from URL https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.9.0rc0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /tmp/pip_build_root...
Double requirement given: tensorflow==0.9.0rc0 from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.9.0rc0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl (already in tensorflow, name='tensorflow')
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1263, in prepare_files
    self.add_requirement(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 989, in add_requirement
    % (install_req, self.get_requirement(name), name))
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Double requirement given: tensorflow==0.9.0rc0 from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.9.0rc0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl (already in tensorflow, name='tensorflow')
```

I have googled and checked the other SO questions for this installation issue but did not find anything related. I will be happy to provide any other environment information necessary for debugging this.

Comment: Can this still be reproduced in tf 1.0?